# Navigating to same subroute throws an error

Tags: angular

In my Angular 6 application I have a main route and a sub route (both same component).

```
  {
    path: 'materiallist',
    component: MaterialListComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'material/:materialNumber', component: MaterialListComponent }
    ]
  },
```

I am in the `MaterialListComponent` and navigate to this subroute it works.

I get an url like this:
`/materiallist/material/1234`

Note: I am still in the `MaterialListComponent`. When I now try to navigate to same subroute, but another parameter

```
this.router.navigate(['/materiallist/material', '9876']);
```

I get an exception:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
    at PreActivation.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.PreActivation.setupRouteGuards (router.js:2692)
    at router.js:2655
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PreActivation.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.PreActivation.setupChildRouteGuards (router.js:2654)
    at PreActivation.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.PreActivation.setupRouteGuards (router.js:2684)
    at router.js:2655
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PreActivation.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.PreActivation.setupChildRouteGuards (router.js:2654)
    at PreActivation.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.PreActivation.initialize (router.js:2627)
    at MapSubscriber.project (router.js:3797)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
```

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers` : please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: Please create a stackbiltz and share

Comment: Do you want to reload same route with diff values?

Comment: @Saxena, Yes, I do